# Overloads don't match on useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

Overloads wont match

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'


function Button() {

  const [ctr, setCtr] = useState(0)
  let interval = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCtr(prev => prev + 1)
    },1000)
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval.current)
    }
  }, [])
  
 
  return (
    <>
      <span> Count : {ctr} </span>
      <button onClick={ () => clearInterval(interval.current) }> Clear </button>
    </>
  )
}

export default Button
```

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(intervalId: Timeout): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Timeout | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Timeout'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Timeout'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(handle?: number | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Timeout | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | undefined'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.ts(2769)
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude `null` from type of `interval.current`

```
<button onClick={ () => clearInterval(interval.current as Timeout) }> Clear </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that setInterval is a window object. The problem here is that TS thinks this is a NodeJS construct while it's just a window function. Using the `as` keyword isn't good practice and should be avoided in most cases. The whole point of typescript is so that it's strong-typed and the usage of `as` deviates from that.

```js
function Button() {

  const [ctr, setCtr] = useState(0)
  const interval = useRef(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    interval.current = window.setInterval(() => {
      setCtr(prev=>prev+1)
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(interval.current);
    };
  }, []);
  
 
  return (
    <>
      <span> Count : {ctr} </span>
      <button onClick={ () => window.clearInterval(interval.current) }> Clear </button>
    </>
  )
}
```